# Add an extra column to my model in an .edmx file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model

I want to add an extra column, similar to a join to my model based on the ID. Is this possible?

For example:

```
ProductsModel

ID
DeliveryID


DeliveryModel

DeliveryID
DeliveryDescription
```

What I'd like to do is add the DeliveryDescription column to my ProductsModel in my .edmx file. I know its possible to add 3 property types (scalar, navigation, complex) are one of these the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Default entities must exactly match your tables. There are situations where this is not the true but all involve advanced mapping features like splitting or inheritance. By looking at your tables neither of this is case.

What you are trying to do is equivalent to database view. It is possible in EF by either using [QueryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716798.aspx) or [DefiningQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738450.aspx). Both will result in new read-only entity type. To use these advanced features you must manually edit EDMX file (and in case of `DefiningQuery` you cannot use update from database any more because it would delete your changes).

You most probably need this for some data presentation so instead of modifying your mapped entities create a new class outside of EF just for presentation and fill it from entities.

Comment: You're right I just need this for data presentation. The problem is, I use a method returns a list of type Product, to return all Products, that why I was wondering if it was possible to add an extra column to the Product model in my .edmx file, because that would have made the process much easier. Maybe one way of getting around this is by using a database view which has that information anyway. Thanks for your help!